# Fit a scikit-learn model in parallel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it possible to fit a scikit-learn model in parallel? Something along the lines of
`model.fit(X, y, n_jobs=20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the model you are trying to fit. Usually it will have an `n_jobs` parameter when you initialize the model. See [glossary on n_jobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n_jobs). For example random forest:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=10)
```

If it is an ensemble method, it makes sense to parallelize because you can fit models separately (see [help page for ensemble methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#parallelization)). [LogisticRegression()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) also has an n_job option but I honestly don't know how much this speeds up the fitting process, if that's your bottle neck. See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894671/speeding-up-sklearn-logistic-regression)

Other methods like elastic net, linear regression or SVM, i don't think there's a parallelization option.